# CSS 3 transofrmation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to flip few DIV elements. To do that I used code below. Problem is that DIV elements are not rotating (transforming). Can someone tell me where's the problem? Regards. I want to flip "card" div.

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("#" + id + " img").classList.toggle("flip");
```

CSS:

```
  #boxcard div{
    float: left;
    width: 100;
    height: 120;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: #B1B1B1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
#boxcard div img {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, 
.flip-container.hover .flipper, 
.flip-container.flip .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="_js/howler.min.js"></script>
      <script src="_js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
      <script src="_js/mem.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css"></style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="picbox">
         <span id="boxbuttons">
         <span class="button" id="rezz">
         Rezultat
         <span id="counter">0</span>
         </span>
         <span class="button" id="ttime">00 : 54</span>
         <span class="button">
         <a onclick="ResetGame();">Reset</a>
         </span> 
         </span>
         <div id="boxcard" align="center">
            <div id="card10" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png" class="" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card11" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png" class="" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card12" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card13" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/sport/96/Volleyball-icon.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card14" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img5.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992640c06707c66a5c0b08a2549c69745dc2c.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card15" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925708af4fb3c954b1d856da1f4d4dcd548a.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card16" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699262833250fa3063b708c41042005fda437d.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card17" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925708af4fb3c954b1d856da1f4d4dcd548a.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card18" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img4.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992601ca0f28ba4a8f7b41f99ee026d7aaed8.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card19" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992568b759acd78f7cbe98b6e4a7baa90e717.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card110" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/sport/96/Volleyball-icon.png" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div id="card111" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/1769925824ea93cbb77ba9e95c1a4cec7f89b80c.png" style="display: none;"></div>

         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe that you are toggling `flip` but the class is `flipper` in the CSS?

Comment: let's see some html...

Comment: where are the `flip-container`s? and the `flipper`s? I don't see them in the html...

Comment: hmm do I need to modify CSS to match my divs in html @shennan?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS and HTML don't relate much to each other. Assuming you want the images inside the `card` elements to rotate, try altering the last part of your CSS to this:

```
#boxcard div img.flip{

  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}
```

Also, remove all that **inline** styling in your HTML. You have `style="display:none;"` peppered throughout your images.

See a fiddle I put together [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9CvYd/). Note that the image of the teacher's hat has been flipped.

If you're looking to add animation into the mix, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/9CvYd/1/) an example of how you might use the `transition` CSS3 property.

Also, please be aware that [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) only has support in modern browsers.

**Reluctant Update**

I'm giving you a [***clickable example***](http://jsfiddle.net/9CvYd/2/). If this doesn't work for you then I would recommend either updating your browser to support transitions/transformations, or hit the library and start brushing up on some JavaScript basics. I hope this last push wields some form of an accepted answer...

Comment: I tried that and images are still not showing/rotaing. Thanks for the help @shennan

Comment: I tried your code (clicked on teacher hat) and it's not rotating. Does your code works for you @shennan?

Comment: @user2496520 you never mentioned anything about clicking in your question. But I have provided you with a ***[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CvYd/1/)*** so you should be able to take what's there and add click events to it.

Comment: I added on click event and they still don't flip. Are you sure that your code is working? When I run your fiddle nothing happens.